# Replace the highest and second highest value in a column with its median

Tags: r

Using R, how to replace the highest and second highest value in a column with its median (i.e. median of other than highest and second highest value)

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried. Also, it would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try something like `vec[order(vec, decreasing = TRUE)][1:2] <- median(vec[order(vec)][1:(length(vec)-2)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function and apply it for each column using `lapply`.

```
replace_by_median <- function(x) {
  inds <- order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]
  x[inds] <- median(x[-inds], na.rm = TRUE)
  x
}

df[] <- lapply(df, replace_by_median)
```

Or in `dplyr` with `across` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(.fns = replace_by_median))
```